# How to Fix : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, ms-access-2010, datetimepicker

Hi Guys I searched a lot on how to fix this but nothing seems working for me I think I'm doing something Wrong which I don't know to fix the issue 1st. I trade the ParseExact method like all of the threads here suggest but still this Error always came out here is my Sample code:

```
Dim startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTimePicker1.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
    Dim endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTimePicker2.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
    Dim count As Integer


    For d As Integer = 0 To ServiceDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        If ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value >= startDate & endDate <= ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value Then
            count = count + 1
            MessageBox.Show(count)
        End If
    Next
```

In this code I'm trying to count all row in a DataGridView that will fall between the chosen start and end date from two DateTimePicker. I don't know if this will work but I have to fix the 1st error 1st so I can validate either it is working or not. The Date format for my DataGridView is this : 30/03/2016 15:51 Just to let you know. Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to format the `DateTimePicker.Text` into `String` and then `Parse` it to `DateTime` to use it. Simply use `DateTimePicker.Value`:

```
Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value 'This is already a DateTime
Dim endDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
Dim count As Integer

For d As Integer = 0 To ServiceDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    If ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value >= startDate & endDate <= ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value Then
        count = count + 1
        MessageBox.Show(count)
    End If
Next
```

That said, depending on how `DateTimePicker.Format` your `DateTimePicker.Text` may look varily:

```
Wednesday, March 30, 2016 'Long
3/30/2016 'Short
```

And thus not matched with your format `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"` and therefore giving you the error.

Comment: Hello thanks It's all working now but I have another problem which I predicted after I have solved this hehehe. And that is counting the row that will fall between the two DateTimePicker from a DataGridView but anyways Thanks.! I will open another thread because this is a different problem! :)

Comment: Although this answers the question is till will not produce the desired result. This will not compile with Option Strict On

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `DataTimePicker1` is actually a `DateTimePicker` control, you can just use the `Value` Property:

```
Dim startDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
```

No conversion to string and back to a date is needed here. [The reason your code failed is probably to do with the fact that the `.ToString` does not produce the date in the exact format you are specifying]

You don't really need to hold this in a variable either, so you can simplify your code quite a lot:

```
Dim count As Integer

For d As Integer = 0 To ServiceDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    If ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value >= DateTimePicker1.Value AndAlso DateTimePicker2.Value <= ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value Then
        count = count + 1
        MessageBox.Show(count)
    End If
Next
```

Note that you have used an `&` where you should have used `AndAlso` - make sure you switch `Option Strict On` to catch things like this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the DateTime values *as is*? Like:

```
Dim startDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim endDate = DateTimePicker2.Value
Dim count As Integer

For d As Integer = 0 To ServiceDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    If ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value >= startDate & endDate <= ServiceDataGridView.Rows(d).Cells(2).Value Then
        count = count + 1
        MessageBox.Show(count)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Gustav thanks for your reply but I already tried that hehehe. I got an error after I have tested it's said Cannot Conver String "dd/mmyyy" to date something.

Comment: But isn't that string the cell value? If so, convert that to DateTime. You always handle date (and time) as `DateTime`, not strings or numbers. No exceptions.

Comment: your code works as well Gustav pardon me! Hehehe the error I got is because the format of my DataGridview and DateTimePicker does not match I configure it to become in short format and it's working fine now thank you helping me realize my mistake! Regards! :)

Comment: Although this answers the question is till will not produce the desired result. This will not compile with Option Strict On